# Fantasy Book With Four Protagonists And Bandoliers

Tags: story-identification, books

Story Summary via vague memories:

This was a paperback book in a medieval fantasy style setting. I don't remember the publish year, but the book was read in the early 00's. The story did seem more recent as far as writing goes, so I suspect it was written no earlier than the late 80s, though I don't trust my instincts in that aspect. There were four protagonists: two elves, female and male, whom knew each other but didn't seem to be involved; and two hobbit/dwarf like people, male and female, who were in love. They were also described to be more child-like in appearance. I will call the latter dwarves moving forward.

The male elf's preferred weapon was a sword if memory serves, and I distinctly remember the female dwarf using throwing knives and a set of bandoliers. During part of the story they are celebrating a natural event (I want to say something like a solstice), and drank crystal clear water as part of the celebration.

I recall the story focusing on the dwarves lives while they were young at some point in the beginning. The story was also notable because at least one, if not both, of the dwarves died at the end.

I don't remember if it was part of a series. My memory leads me to believe this was a one-off story, but I don't trust my memory in this aspect.

It has been recommended that it might be in the **Dragonlance** world, since the dwarves sound suspiciously like kender. Unfortunately, I can't say for certain if that's the case. The dwarves definitely didn't seem as how the kender are described to behave, but that could also be failing memory.

Another recommendation was that it might be related to **The Halfblood Chronicles** but the summaries I can find don't seem to fit. For instance, I don't remember a theme of slavery.

I'm hoping I can find the book/series and re-read them, along with passing them on to my children.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Any recollection of the cover art?  Childlike knife-using diminutive race in a fantasy setting suggests "Kender" to me, does that ring a bell?

Comment: @DavidW No recollection of the cover art. My friend suggested "kender" which *sounded* familiar, but unfortunately I'm concered it sounds familiar because of the miasma of memories. At the time I read this book I was given a large box of fantasy stories, with everything from Game of Thrones to Redwall, Wheel of Time, and more. I also did a lot of searching based on "kender" and couldn't find anything. I can add it to my question, but I'm concerned it would be a red herring.

Comment: @DavidW I added your recommendation of "Kender" just in case. I don't *think* that's it but since my memory is bad on the book I'm going to assume I could also be wrong.

Comment: Updated to include a recommendation from another friend that it might be The Halfblood Chronicles...doesn't seem to fit my memory, though.

Comment: Made me think of Dennis McKiernan's Mithgar books.  The 3 ([The Iron Tower Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Tower)) involve Warrow--hobbit-like folk.  They are short enough that the three could be read as a single book.  The history of the publishing is...sketchy and pulls strongly from Lord of the Rings, but the series diverges after that.

Comment: @eshier You might be on to something. I will look and see if that's it, but it *does* sound familiar.

Comment: @eshier Your suggestion bore fruit. The book is titled "Eye of the Hunter". Once I looked it up I immediately recognized the book cover. Care to supply it as an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggested that this reminded me of the Warrows in [Dennis McKiernan's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_L._McKiernan) Mithgar books.  The OP responded that this was indeed the case and, specifically, it was [*Eye of the Hunter*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/426943.The_Eye_of_the_Hunter?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=IeJDh2cYK1&rank=1).

Goodreads summary:

> A thousand years had passed since the Eye of the Hunter last glared in the heavens. A thousand years since the immortal Elfess Riatha brought word of the prophecy to the Warrows Tomlin and Petal with whom she had leagued to hunt down and defeat Baron Stoke, one of the most evil beings to ever stalk the lands of Mithgar. The price of Stoke's doom had been a beloved companion's life, the two plunging, locked in combat, down an icy chasm which had sealed shut the ring of eternity. Now the comet known as the Eye of the Hunter again rode Mithgar's skies, and the creatures of darkness once again ravaged the lands, heralding the imminent return of their dread master, Baron Stoke. And now five brave souls must answer the call of prophecy: Riatha and the Elf called Aravan; Gwylly and Faeril, last in a long line of Firstborn Warrow descendants of Tomlin and Petal; and one other, one restored to them from Death's chill grasp...

[image: Three human-sized characters and two Warrow (halflings) hide on the left behind a wall as creatures pass by their position.]

The book is a stand-alone within the greater series.

---

The series has an interesting origin explained in McKiernan's biography.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'm excited to be able to revisit this book, and share it with my kids. Thank you again!

Comment: Happy I could help.  Good news is there are a lot of books set in the world.  You actually inspired me--I was in between book series and the original 5 are all on kindle unlimited, so I started rereading them last night.